# cdk virtual scroll issue when ever scrolling it down items are getting displayed slowly and sometimes blank for 2 secs

Tags: css, angular-material, angular7, virtualscroll, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

i am using angular virtual scroll in project so when ever i am scrolling it down items are loading but flickering for micro sec

trying with maxBufferPx and minBufferPx and positions to fix but not working need any solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `templateCacheSize` in `*cdkVirtualFor`, remove it.
if the issue is the same try to set it greater than 20, because 20 is its default value.
it worked for me when I set `templateCacheSize: 30`.